# python PIL manually convert 16bits TIF to 8bits JPG

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I have a database of grayscale 16bits tif images, whose pixels range approx from 768 to 1280 (very dark). I want to strech the data from the extrema value and save the result in a 8bits jpg.

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open(inp_16bits)
image.mode = 'I'
mi, ma = image.getextrema()
ratio = 256.0 / (ma - mi)
mapping = lambda i: (i-mi) * ratio
image.point(mapping).convert('L').save(out_8bits)
```

My mapping function is working, but doesn't work as a parameter for point, my code return

> "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: '_E' and 'int'".

How to properly implement my function as to make it work with Image.point ? or is there an easy way to create a lookup table from my function mapping ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the _E object constructor I found     `__add__` and     `__mul__` methods.

```
lambda i: (i.__add__(-mi)).__mul__(ratio)# doesnt work but 
lambda i: (i * ratio).__add__(-mi*ratio)# works
```

The first one returns

> ValueError: illegal expression.

I didn't want to struggle with that so I tried different way to implement my operation and finally the second one did work.